# Cohomology with compact supports

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I am trying to understand the (singular/Čech) cohomology with compact supports for topological manifolds.

Let $X$ be a topological manifold. Consider its one-point compactification $i\colon X\to X^+$ and the inclusion of the point at infinity $j\colon +\to X^+$. 
The cohomology with compact supports can be calculated as $H_c(X) = \ker j^*$, where $j^*$ is the induced map
$$H^*(X^+) \xrightarrow{j^*} H^*(+)$$
However cohomology with compact supports can be treated as a covariant functor with respect to open inclusions, what gives a map 
$$i_*\colon H_c^*(X)\to H^*(X^+).$$

> Is the inclusion $H_c^*(X)=\ker j^* \subseteq H^*(X^+)$ the same as $i_*$?

I can prove this for *compact* $X$, where $X^+ = X\cup +$. I would appreciate any hints, or even better, a book recommendation.